# sqlite database

Tags: ios4

i have huge data in xlsx format and i want to dump that data into sqlite database ...
can any one help me how to do that one

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very easy to implement.Just export the table into .csv format and then goto the SQLite browser and import that .csv file.Click File->Select Import table from CSV file option.In this way you can easily implement what you want.

Cheers